# Helm chart strategy for separate (subsequent) deployments using identical stateful dependency

Tags: database, deployment, kubernetes-helm, dependency-management

I'm trying to write my first Helm chart and wondering how to best handle a certain scenario: two deployments (backends) that share an identical dependency (database), but where I want to be able to deploy each backend at separate times.

I'll try to illustrate with an example:

- On Monday, John deploys **Backend A**, which depends on Postgres.
- On Tuesday, John deploys **Backend B**, which ideally depends on the identical Postgres instance

I'd like Backend B to use Backend A's Postgres instance, if it exists, otherwise, setup a new one. And vice versa, if possible - someone deploys Backend B first, Backend A would re-use the Postgres. It seems `CREATE DATABASE ...` ostensibly would need to run so each backend had it's own DB, but not sure this is possible.

What are recommended paths to accomplish this using Helm?

Comment: I see docs [mention](https://helm.sh/docs/glossary/#chart-dependency-subcharts) 'soft' vs 'hard' dependencies, meanwhile the [parent/child](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/release-2.16/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md#overriding-values-of-a-child-chart) docs seem to suggest there should be one parent. So would Postgres be the parent in my scenario?

Comment: What are the downsides in using a single chart and making the backends configurable? 
e.g. `helm install myapp --set backendB.enabled = true`? It seems smoother to have each backend live in its own chart, but not sure if that's feasible

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend having each service deploy its own database.  Have both backends A and B list a PostgreSQL dependency in their `requirements.yaml` (or Helm 3 `Chart.yaml`) files, and have each connect to `{{ .Release.Name }}-postgres`.  Don't try to share a database.

If it's really important to you to share a database, deploy it separately.  `helm install stable/postgres`, or use your cloud provider's hosted database system (like Amazon RDS).  Then configure the two backend charts' Helm values to point to that externally managed database.

Helm doesn't really have the concept of conditionally deploying things based on the existing state in the cluster: when you deploy backend B, Helm can't look at the cluster and say "backend A already has a database so I won't deploy my own".  There's a similar problem if you go to uninstall A; it won't know that B has a dependency on one of its components.  In the link you cite in a comment, this is exactly the "soft dependency" case, where "dependencies may be managed separately".

Comment: Thanks! The reason for leaning towards a single database is mostly controlling cloud provider costs. I've noticed the performance of a certain well-known provider's managed Postgres has been not so impressive at the lower SKUs and I think I know why :)

The more I think about this the more it seems preferable to separate out the stateful things into their own management cycle. My hope was to deliver 'single click deploys' using Helm, but it seems it will have be two clicks this time. Cheers David